How to install client certificate to Android
I have an MDM application for Android phones. I need to take the certificate from the Download folder and install it on Android.
I have written a function to install it (correct me if this is wrong). Now how do I get this certificate (I need it to work with it and also to access it from another app)?
I couldn't find any example in the documentation on how to use it, and no article either. I wrote a function, but it doesn't find the private key.
The certificate has the extension ".pfx" (PKCS12). The certificate is created by a certificate authority. The user will enter a password when installing the certificate.
Please note that this is a client certificate and I need a password to work with it
I tried installing it via intent. It crashes with an error. I need MDM to be able to install and select the certificates itself
override fun installCertificate(certificate: File, password: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[installCertificate] Start install certificate certificate: $certificate | password: $password")

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE)
        FileInputStream(certificate).use { fis -> keyStore.load(fis, password.toCharArray()) }

        val alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement()
        val key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray()) as PrivateKey
        val certChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias)
        val dpm = activity.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        val adminComponentName = LegacyUtils.getAdminComponentName(activity)

        val certData = secretEncryptor.getCertificate(keyStore) as? X509Certificate ?: throw Exception()
        val certificateAlias = certData.subjectX500Principal.name
        val isOverwrite = dpm.installKeyPair(adminComponentName, key, certChain, alias, 0)
        lastAlias = alias

        Log.i(TAG,
            "[installCertificate] Certificate $certificate installed | alias: $lastAlias | isOverwrite: $isOverwrite")
    }


private fun getCertificate(alias: String) {
        KeyChain.getPrivateKey(activity, alias)?.let { privateKey ->
            KeyChain.getCertificateChain(activity, alias)?.let { certChain ->
                val certificate = certChain.firstOrNull()
                if (certificate != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "[getCertificate] Сертификат найден | alias: $alias")
                    // TODO: work with certificate
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "[getCertificate] Certificate not found | alias: $alias")
                }
            } ?: run {
                Log.e(TAG, "[getCertificate] No certificate chain found | alias: $alias")
            }
        } ?: run {
            Log.e(TAG, "[getCertificate] Private key not found | alias: $alias")
        }
    }

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            getCertificate(lastAlias)
        }

[checkCertificatesAndInstallIfExist] certificates: [/storage/emulated/0/Download/cert.pfx]
2024-08-06 11:08:25.473 15588-15588 CertificatesManagerImp  com.hmdm.launcher                    I  [installCertificate] Start install certificate certificate: /storage/emulated/0/Download/cert.pfx | password: 1234
2024-08-06 11:08:26.375 15588-15588 CertificatesManagerImp  com.hmdm.launcher                    I  [installCertificate] Certificate /storage/emulated/0/Download/cert.pfx installed | alias: tq-70b931d7-cb80-4e2e-a617-c4d59435b8f4 | isOverwrite: true
2024-08-06 11:08:27.498 15588-15659 CertificatesManagerImp  com.hmdm.launcher                    E  [getCertificate] Private key not found | alias: tq-70b931d7-cb80-4e2e-a617-c4d59435b8f4

I also tried getting a certificate through KeyStore. All calls return null and an exception in LogCat
private fun getCertificate(alias: String) {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)

        val key1 = keyStore.getKey(alias, null)
        val key2 = keyStore.getKey(alias, "1234".toCharArray())
        val certificate1 = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias)
        val certificate2 = keyStore.getCertificate(alias)
        val certificate3 = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null) as? KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry
        Log.i(TAG, "[getCertificate] Certificate $certificate3 | alias: $alias ")
    }

2024-08-06 18:01:03.781  6289-6878  KeyStore                com.hmdm.launcher                   W  KeyStore exception
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 7)
                                                                                                    
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2085)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
    at android.security.keystore.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.get(IKeystoreService.java:978)
    at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:236)
    at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:225)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetCertificate(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:165)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificate(KeyStore.java:1120)
    at com.hmdm.launcher.certificates.CertificatesManagerImp.getCertificate(CertificatesManagerImp.kt:109)
    at com.hmdm.launcher.certificates.CertificatesManagerImp.access$getCertificate(CertificatesManagerImp.kt:29)
    at com.hmdm.launcher.certificates.CertificatesManagerImp$getAllCertificates$1.invokeSuspend(CertificatesManagerImp.kt:98)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)


did you try unbundling the pfx and installing them individually?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
